# Can Grails output error messages in emacs format?

Tags: emacs, grails, ant, groovy

Ant has a `-e` option for outputting error messages that can be parsed by emacs' `compile` command.  For example, it is possible to do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compile`, `ant -e`, then navigate to any errors with <kbd>C-x `</kbd>.

Is it possible to make grails output its compilation errors in this format?  Alternatively, is there an emacs variable that can be customized to handle error messages in the format that grails uses?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what grails errors look like, but you can probably use `compilation-error-regexp-alist`.  It's quite flexible.